# api level mismatch while using NotificationCompact

Tags: android

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
    startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

My minSdkVersion="8" so i get error while i do the code above. 
I tried doing this using support library

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new  NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
    mBuilder
    .setContentTitle("Service")
    .setContentText("Service is running")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .build();
    //now how to perform startForeground
```

I need to perform startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification), but i don't have notification object.
Also i need to do notification.setLatestEventInfo(.....)

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: I need to perform startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification), but i don't have notification object